# Corporate proxy error with urls that contains '-'. Angular

Tags: angular, proxy

I have configured a corporate proxy inside my angular app following this common solution:

```js
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxyConfig = [
    {
        context: '/api/*',
        target: 'https://somehost/app/',
        secure: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/api": "/api"
        }
    }
];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
    var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
    if (proxyServer) {
        var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
        console.log('Using corporate proxy server: ' + proxyServer);
        proxyConfig.forEach(function (entry) {
            entry.agent = agent;
        });
    }
    return proxyConfig;
}
```

For example: APIs that follow the next format are ok:
http://localhost:4200/api/users
or api/resourceX
etc

but for example, APIs that have the next format give an error from the backend side (400 not found)
http://localhost:4200/api/users/abc012-dawd012-423423

I don't know if maybe I need to scape the '-' or something. It's really confusing because the rest of API calls are working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with the definition of the context.
This is the correct config:
context: '/api',